# Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None' with name '', namespace ''

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I've been searching for the past 4 hours for ways on how to tackle this problem, and I've not yet found a solution.

I'm building an API with .NET and wish to parse JSON information that is sent back from API calls.

My current approach does the following:

```
private void PostNewPlayer(HttpContext context)
{
    // Create the serializer
    context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

    DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ASPlayer));
    ASPlayer p = (ASPlayer)json.ReadObject(context.Request.InputStream);  <-- Exception here
    Int32 playerId = ASPlayerManager.InsertNewPlayer(p);
}
```

But I currently get an Exception at the indicated line.   I have made sure my class implements the correct serialization namespaces:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

The class I am trying to serialize has had its DataContract and Member fields set accordingly:

```
[DataContract]
public class ASPlayer
{
    [DataMember]
    private string _name;
    public string player_name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    private string _location;
    public string player_location
    {
       get { return _location; }
       set { _location = value; }
    }

    // Other vars
    ... 

    public ASPlayer(string name, string location)
    {
        _name = name;
        _location = location;
     }
}
```

However, when I use a HTTP client such as Postman to make a request I get the error stated in the question title

[image]

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was a very bad mistake on my behalf, but for those who encounter this in future make sure you send your JSON object in Postman through the Raw field. In my case I simply did:

```
{
  "player_name": "Test",
  "player_location": "EUW",
  "player_wins":10,
  "player_draws":10,
  "player_losses":15,
  "player_points":20
}
```

This fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I think you marked the wrong variables, this:

```
[DataMember]
private string _name;
public string player_name
```

should be this:

```
private string _name;
[DataMember]
public string player_name
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried marking the variables both ways and still no luck :( any other ideas?

Comment: It would help if you post your JSON

Comment: I think I've just spotted what I've done wrong.  Im sending the parameters in the header, I should be posting a json object. Oops!

Comment: @thumbmunkeys - ordering is only important for `DataContractSerializer`.  `DataContractJsonSerializer` ignores property order since JSON object properties are defined to be [unordered](http://json.org/).